# Why numpy.array() use much more RAM than python list?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from sys import getsizeof

def get_csv_data(csv_file):
    """get csv data"""
    csv_data = []
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row_data in csv_reader:
            csv_data.append(row_data)
    return csv_data


def get_nparray_size():
    p = r'D:\PySpace\DataAnalysisReport\testdata\bbb\test.csv'
    csv_data = get_csv_data(p)
    print('origin size:', getsizeof(csv_data))
    np_data = np.array(csv_data)
    print('np array size:', np_data.nbytes)
```

this csv file is 81rows, 1168columns

then output:

**origin size: 768,
np array size: 447685056**

I wonder why the result is like this?

Comment: 81*1168=94608 so `getsizeof(csv_data)` probably does not reflect the real size of the data

Comment: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/ looks like something you could look at (found on [the official Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof))

Comment: `getsizeof` only gives you the size of the list object itself, not the items it contains.

Answer (score 2):

`getsizeof` does not reflect the full memory usage of the variable, but just considers the basic object size. For your CSV, it will be a 2D array, where only a single dimension is accounted for if I understand it well; but the storage for the actual numbers in there will be overlooked.

See also [this blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202002/sysgetsizeof_is_not_what_you_want.html) for a more comprehensive explanation.